# How can I get the selected item of a dropdownlist, the first time my page loads?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for a solution to get the first selected item in a DropDownList. And I want to get it when the page loads for the first time.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I call this method at the Load-event but ddlNiveau2 remains empty. I think that ddlNiveau1.SelectedValue isn't accessed.

```
public void FillListNiveau2()
{
    ddlNiveau2.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in dBAL.GetListNiveau2(ddlNiveau1.SelectedValue))
    {
        ddlNiveau2.Items.Add(item.ToString());
    }
    RemoveDuplicateItems(ddlNiveau2);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details to clear question.

Comment: I use a DataSource to fill my dropdownlist. And I want, when my page loads for the first time in history :P, get the selected value at that time. is it possible?

Comment: Updated question, take a look.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a `DataBound event`, which fires after the data is bound to the dropdown. As you are assigning the dataSource to your dropdown you need selected item after all the rows binded to dropdown

```
protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue // store it in some variable
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the Selected Value like

```
string selected = drp.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Or

```
string selected = drp.SelectedItem.Value;
```

When the page is loaded the first value is shown `Selected` unless you set it by specifying the `SelectedIndex` or by `Text/Value`

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in the `Page_Load` event handler:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

    // Load list items ..
    dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;

}
```

---

Refer to [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) class form more info.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads first time, there is no selected value in drop down until your code sets it using dropdown.SelectedValue property. This is the first time the page is loading and user has not interacted with the drop down yet , so it doesn't make sense to get the selected value

Comment: doesn't make sense? I use a datasource, this fills my dropdownlist at load-event.

Comment: And how are we supposed to know that if you dont give us that information before tassisto?