# ASP.NET WebForms, DropDowns, Submit Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have struggled to find a solution to this problem through lots of Google searching and documentation reading, and even looking at others’ source code, but I am putting it here in the hopes that someone knows how to help me or has specific experience in dealing with such a thing.

I am currently working on an ASP.NET WebForms project with some of my colleagues, and we have decided to go with an option of which I was not a fan. We have created a page where the user will be required to fill out the university classes they have taken, with related data, in a massive sheet of dropdown menus.

These dropdown menus are pulling their associated data for the user to choose from the database (SQL Server, a.k.a. “Microsoft SQL”), as a way to partially limit user error. The user will make their selections on none, one, some, or multiple dropdowns from multiple “rows” on this page.

My question is how I can write an SQL Server query, and thus, stored procedure, that will allow for a “submit” or “save changes” button to be added to this page. When a user clicks this button, presumably, all of the changes that they have made on any of these “rows” – one row per class – will be added to the database for their respective user account.

My suggestion was having that page be an ASP.NET Grid View that would update with the classes that the user had taken as they entered them. There would be a button at the top of the page where the user could click “Add Class”, and they would be taken to a model popup or some other page, and they would enter the details of that class, mostly through predefined information that is pulled from the database. In the case of an administrator user, they would essentially be able to put whatever information in for the class, because they have the ability to override the strictly regulated format for regular (student) users.

Comment: What exactly are looking for? You want to show "submit" or "save changes" button using SQL query?

Comment: The user will select several options from drop down menus on each row. When they are done, they will click the “submit” button. Any changes that they have made need to be saved to the database. I need the SQL Query that goes in that button so that the changes will be made.

Comment: Well...  there are several ways to do that.. and they all depends on the way you are consuming SQL database. How are you connecting to database via ADO.NET or Entity Framework? In either case, you'll have to create a Stored Procedure in database and call it.

Comment: Whether you are using EF or ADO.NET, you basically just need to grab the selected values and perform a basic insert/update SQL statement with query params (to avoid SQL Injection).

Comment: Thank you, @IrishChieftain. What do you mean by ‘grab the selected values’? Can you show me a simple example or something like that?

Comment: @EduardoRamirez, You need code to insert into database or taking values from dropdown?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961488/how-can-i-get-the-selected-item-of-a-dropdownlist-the-first-time-my-page-loads